# Create video file with multiple audio tracks?

Tags: audio

I have an animated movie in three different languages. The picture is exactly the same for each langauge, only the audio is different.

I want to merge all these files into one, so that I have a single video file where I can switch easily between the audio tracks in VLC.

How can I merge the audio tracks into a single file?

I can use any OS for the job, but my preferred order is:

1. OS X
2. Linux (Debian/Ubuntu/Mint)
3. Android
4. iOS
5. Windows desktop

It's not really important, though, I'll take suggestions for any platform happily.

The only function I really need is the merging itself. Lightweight solutions are a a plus.

I prefer GUI solutions.

Comment: Crossposting is discouraged. And you're unlikely to get a different answer.

Comment: @Mulvya I'm sorry, I just really want to find the solution to this. A different answer from what?

Comment: The one I gave. ffmpeg is pretty much the only tool that does this for most formats. If your videos are MKV, then [MKVToolnix](http://www.videohelp.com/software/MKVtoolnix) will also work.

Comment: @Mulvya I'm not comfortable with CLI. And for the the GUI options you linked to, I couldn't find the function. But I think I've found a way to do it though. The sources are all DVDs, btw.

Comment: @Mulvya Yes, MKVToolnix was very nice. Someone described it to me in detail here: apple.stackexchange.com/a/239676/153510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFMPEG can do it. FFMPEG is command line video (and audio) processing software, available [here](http://ffmpeg.org).

If you have FFMPEG here is the command you would use:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -codec copy output
```